# update the Viewcontroller based on Network Availblilty in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to ios development, i have to check the internet network based on that i will show the view controllers, i used this code for test the network.

```
class Connectivity {
    class func isConnectedToInternet() ->Bool {
        return NetworkReachabilityManager()!.isReachable
    }
}

 if Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet() {
            print("Yes! internet is available.")
            // do some tasks..
        }
        else {

        }
```

with this code i am getting network network status, my aim is when the application launch time if don't have network show the default page, if enable the network automatically it will show the main page please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
let reachability = Reachability()!


NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reachabilityChanged(note:)), name: .reachabilityChanged, object: reachability)
    do{
      try reachability.startNotifier()
    }catch{
      print("could not start reachability notifier")
    }

    @objc func reachabilityChanged(note: Notification) {

        let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

        switch reachability.connection {
        case .wifi:
            print("Reachable via WiFi")
        case .cellular:
            print("Reachable via Cellular")

        case .none:
            print("Network not reachable")
        }
    }
```